# Alterar a quandidade de elementos de forma automatica

Tags: html, css, html5, aplicação-web

Preciso criar uma div com x(Quantidade variada) elementos(pode ser outras divs ou botões) na qual a quantidade delas possam ser alteradas de forma automática apena mudando o valor de uma variável EX: agora preciso ter 50, depois 100, e depois apenas 10, estou com dificuldade de fazer isso alterando apenas uma única variável quantidade, alguém. tem uma ideia de como realizar.

Comment: O que você já tentou fazer? Edite a pergunta e coloque seu código.

Answer (score -1):

Se entendi bem precisa criar uma div com vária divs dentro de acordo com uma váriável.
Se for isso pode utilizar javaScript:

```
<script>
  let vaiavel_qnt_element = 10
  for(var i=0; i <= variavel_qnt_element; i++ )
    {
      var teste = `<div style ="border:1px solid #000; background-color:#ccc;">${i}</div>` ;
      document.write(teste);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Mesmo se essa resposta solucionasse a pergunta essa não seria a melhor das abordagens, não soluciona pois o AP quer também que ao modificar `vaiavel_qnt_element` o número de elementos dentro do componente criado reflita a modificação. Para cada elemento o usuário teia que adicionar mais código js. O uso de `document.write()` para criar componentes é inviável em produção. Algo nas especificações do AP talvez deva ser feita usando [Templates e Slots](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_components/Using_templates_and_slots) mas não é possível determinar baseado na pergunta.